# How to keep WAR files running in Tomcat while I'm using IntelliJ?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

There are two WAR files that rarely change and it should be running in my machine.

The tomcat path is /Users/myuser/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.53 and the tomcat server in IntelliJ configuration use it also.

If I deploy the WARs in webapps directory, run another Java project that uses Tomcat in IntelliJ then I can't access these WARs. It seems like these wars are missing but there are in webapp path.

After stop tomcat server in IntelliJ I got these WARs available again.

In order to solve the problem, my current project configuration builds and deploys these WARs every time but it takes more time. How can I solve this?

```
Tomcat Server
Running
My project [local]
sec-web-services:war exploded [Republish] (first war file that rarely changes)
documents-web-services:war exploded [Republish] (second war file that rarely changes)
api-web-services:war exploded [Republish]
project-webapp:war exploded [Republish]
```

Tomcat Server Config in IntelliJ

```
Tomcat Home /Users/myuser/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.53
Tomcat base directory /Users/myuser/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.53
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA Tomcat run configuration has an option to deploy applications already present in `webapps` directory:

[image: deploy]